# How can I show the numbering of slides of each frame?

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

In beamer, when `\only`s used, how can I make the page numbers reflect them?

For example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[sectionpage=none,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \only<1>{
    Slide 1--1
  }
  \only<2>{
    Slide 1--2
  }
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \only<1>{
    Slide 2--1
  }
  \only<2>{
    Slide 2--2
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have page numbers to be `1--1`, `1--2`, `2--1`, `2--2` on these 4 slides, respectively.

Another example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme[sectionpage=none,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \textcolor<2>{red}{\color<3,8>{blue} Hi}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 3
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Slides 1 and 3 should not show the post-dash part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[sectionpage=none,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\newcounter{slideinframe}

\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{%
    \ifnum\insertframeendpage>\insertframestartpage
        \setcounter{slideinframe}{\thepage}%
        \addtocounter{slideinframe}{-\insertframestartpage}%
        \addtocounter{slideinframe}{1}%
        \insertframenumber{} -- \theslideinframe%
      \else
        \insertframenumber{}
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \textcolor<2>{red}{\color<3,18>{blue} Hi}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

With an up-to-date beamer version, the code can be simplified to:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[sectionpage=none,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{%
  \ifnum\insertframeendpage>\insertframestartpage{}
        \insertframenumber{} -- \insertoverlaynumber{}%
  \else
        \insertframenumber{}
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \textcolor<2>{red}{\color<3,18>{blue} Hi}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Slide 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've always wondered why something like this is not pre-programmed in `beamer`...

Comment: @campa It kind of is, just not in a single counter as beamer treats new slides caused by overlays and new slides caused by things like `allowframebreak` separately.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to have single-slide frames not having the post-dash part?

Comment: @xuhdev please see my updated answer

Comment: It seems that single-slide frames after multi-slide frames are broken...

Comment: @xuhdev ? I thought my example is exactly that. Can you make a MWE that shows the problem?

Comment: See my update. I actually suspect this might be a bug somewhere, because replacing 8 with other numbers (4, 5, 7) would not incur this issue...

Comment: @xuhdev Thanks for the example! It turned out that my if case had a problem with 2 digit page numbers - I restructured it a bit. Can you test again?